# I cannot get the if/else to work properly with my powershell script

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to move our service accounts first names to last names and keep it up to date as service accounts are created in Active Directory. It works and logs the changes, except the else part of the script. For some reason, it will not execute the else statement when the if isn't true. Please keep in mind that I am still a beginner to PowerShell...

```
$runStartTime = Get-Date -Format g
$workingDir = "c:\bin\"
$logfile = $workingDir +" LastNameChg.txt"

Add-Content $logfile "-----|   LogFile: $logfile"
Add-Content $logfile "-----|   Users last names changed in Active Directory on $runStartTime :"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=Testing,OU=Service Accounts,DC=test,DC=907,DC=local" -LDAPFilter {(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(mail=*)(!(sn=*)))} 
foreach ($user in $users){
  $logdata = $user.sAMAccountName
   if ($user.GivenName -ne $null){
    Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADUser -surname $($user.givenName) -givenname $()
    Add-Content $logfile "-----|   $logdata" 
   }
   else{
   Add-Content $logfile "-----|    No changes made to Active Directory"
   }
   }   
    Add-Content $logfile ""
```

Comment: Try `if ($user.GivenName -ne ""){` - maybe the GivenName is either some text or an empty string, and is never $null. Just guessing.

Comment: `$user.GivenName` is most likely `""` (an empty string) and not `$null`. Remove `-ne $null` from the if statement and it'll work

Comment: I tried it both ways, the else statement is still not working, any other ideas?

Comment: I would actually use `if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($user.GivenName))` which catches null, whitespace, or empty

Comment: All of these work in the if statement perfectly, but the else statement is still not doing anything. Could it be a powershell version issue?PSVersion                      4.0

Comment: Do you mean that the else path is never taken, or do you mean that the else path is taken, but does nothing?

Comment: Walter, thanks again for your time. To me it seems like the else path is skipped no matter what, it's either the if path or nothing from what I am experiencing.

Comment: Do you know how many users have no GivenName in the data?

Comment: Right now no users have a givenname, so I would think the else block would execute, but so far I can't get it to work. Logic must be wrong some where, but I can't see it.

Comment: There's no need to do string concatanation here `$logfile = $workingDir +" LastNameChg.txt"`.  Replace that with `$logfile = "$workingDir\LastNameChg.txt"`

Comment: Thanks Fox, I will keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 1):

Look over this writeup of the four different kinds of nulls in PS.

http://www.codykonior.com/2013/10/17/checking-for-null-in-powershell/

Some of these tests give couterintuitive results.  Maybe your variable is a string, in which case PS assigns an empty string to the variable.  Then when the test is done against $null,  it's always not equal, and the else is never chosen.

I'm not saying this is your problem, but it's a real gotcha, so it's worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I read through it and it doesn't seem to be my problem from what I can see, I even tried a few examples. I actually removed the $null from the script to see if that would fix the issue and so far no go.

Comment: It was possibly an answer, if his problem was caused by any of the gotchas in the referenced page.  It turned out not to get him out of the woods, but it was not intended as a critique of the question.  I provided a comment on the question for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who has responded, I figured out the problem with my logic. The if statement needed to go before the loop

```
if ($users){
foreach ($user in $users){
$logdata = $user.sAMAccountName
Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADUser -surname $($user.givenName) -givenname $()
Add-Content $logfile "-----|   $logdata" 
  } 
  }else{Add-Content $logfile "-----|   No Changes Made in Active Directory"}
  Add-Content $logfile ""
```

Comment: Ah.  I (and perhaps others) misunderstood your intent, based on the code you provided.  The logic error is not specific to Powershell.  It could have been made in anything from Basic to Java.